# Polymer calculate width of container paper-scroll-header-panel

Tags: javascript, polymer

I need to calculate the actual container width of the mainContainer set by `paper-scroll-header-panel`.
I can get the element itself with:

```
document.querySelector('#mainContainer')
```

But when I try adding `.width`, `.innerWidth` or `.scrollWidth`, it all returns 0. What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at the native DOM methods https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements? (Also, I'm not really sure what the question has to do with polymer)

Comment: Thanks, but all those methods return 0, also for the div inside the mainContainer while the console returns width values. But thanks to this I thought of another way of working and just get the width of the first div that actually holds some text, which returns some values.

Comment: Ok. Can you add an [mcve] of the HTML, CSS, and JS? Otherwise it is going to be difficult to help out.

Comment: use `.getBoundingClientRect()` . this returns left, top, bottom, right and width of the element

Comment: Yes, but it gave all 0. But by using another element inside the mainContainer, I have been able to determine the width.

Comment: @Vims tell me where do You want to use it? Maybe You could use some properties of that element itself?